# c sharp asp net core entity framework web app - for each and adding values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a rewarding system for a question and answers website where 5 answers is worth one reward. So every time a user answers 5 questions, they get one reward and so on for the next 5 questions they answer again.

For now I have if statements for when the answer count is 5 or 10 or 15 etc, the user is redirected to a rewards notification but it doesn't look good as I will need to do several if statements for 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 and so on.

Is there any way I can code this, maybe an foreach statement or something similar? Maybe how every 5 new answers is added, this equals to 1 reward.

Thanks, sorry if it unclear. Let me how to make it clearer, im new at this.

```
Code in AnswersController:

public async <TaskIAction> Index()
{
int answerCount = _context.Answers.Where( a => a.UserId == userId).Count();

ViewBag.answerCount = answerCount;
if (answerCount == 5)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(RewardsMessage));
}
else if (answerCount == 10)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(RewardsMessage));
}

return View()
```

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Please [edit] and use the code formatting tool to include your code as text.

Comment: This question is not related to asp.net or javascript at all, only pure c#, please remove not related tags from your question.

Comment: the screenshot is not very nice, why didn't you try using the key `Print Screen`? it's built-in and convenient, giving the best quality.

Comment: Regarding formatted text, vs an image of text: Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which lists many reasons why this is important. A photograph or screengrab of code really isn't helpful or readable to all.

Comment: @KingKing - even clean screen-captures aren't really acceptable (see the link I just posted in comments) - very limiting. Formatted text is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidMakogon actually there is a little bit sarcasm in my words :) I know for sure about avoiding screenshot of code (not even need to read that link you've shared, actually I've never had to read that and will never).

Comment: @KingKing - the link wasn't for you, but contains many reasons, some I hadn't even considered until originally reading the post (e.g. screen readers). As for sarcasm... well, this is a fairly new person to SO, posting for the first time. Is sarcasm the best way to welcome new users?

Comment: @DavidMakogon first you commented `see the link I just posted in comments` to me, that means you told me to see the link, so even it's not for me? Second, I would give my next comments if the user responds to me, like a friendly chat. That's a bit funny, so how do you know what my next comments are? Finally I may talk about not using screenshot of code.

Comment: sorry if it is unclear. I have added the code as using the code formatting tool. let me how to make it clearer, im new at this. thanks

Comment: The question is clear. Just working with the screenshot was not that comfortable. Please check the answer below. If it was not the thing you were looking - than it might require some additional details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the reminder after the division on 5 is 0

```
if ((answerCount > 0) && (answerCount % 5 == 0)) 
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(RewardMessage));
}
```